# Header and footer load every time when load any jsp page in spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jsp, header

My spring boot application has a custom wrapper tag named custom-wrapper.tag.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
           <div>
               <c:import url="/view/intranet/header.jsp"/>
            </div>
```

In my other jsp page where I use this tag such as dashboard.jsp

```
<%@taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<t:custom-wrapper title="Dashboard" bodyheader="Dashboard">
    <jsp:attribute name="script">

    </jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:body>
<%-- My body contents here --%>

    </jsp:body>
</t:custom-wrapper>
```

I have 10 numbers of jsp pages whose use this tag. But problem is that when I switch other jsp page header also reloaded.
But I don't want to reload header every time when switch another page.
So I need help from you.

Comment: But this is how JSP works.

Comment: Can u show us a whole page where you use this 2 things?
I think you hav a logic templating problem.